# How to split on new line in angular

Tags: angularjs

I tried some thing like this but getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.filter('newlines', function(){
    return function(text){
        return text.split('\n');
    };
})
```

Html:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="numbers" ng-trim="true" placeholder="Numbers in one per line format" ng-repeat="n in numbers | newlines"></textarea>
```

Comment: What's the content of `numbers`?

Comment: @yarons it is string

Comment: you shouldn't get an error try this https://plnkr.co/edit/w8FA9HBtOMRTagbHFUVp?p=preview Enter numbers in that textbox with shift+enter for new lines. there is a div under it(which repeats)

Answer (score -1):

You need get a split in value in an array.

```
filter('newlines', function(){
return function(text){
var array=[];
   array=text.split('\n');
    return array[0] // or if u want second part array[1]
};
})
```

Comment: Split by \n is great idea. That is work for me.